# What is the current (2021) state-of-the-art theory of emotions?

Tags: emotion, neuropsychology, affective-neuroscience

**Human emotions**, from **a scientific perspective**, is still quite a blurry topic. There is no clear distinction between feelings, emotions, affects. Even in scientific context most of the time we are using those terms with their dictionary, or rather 'common-sense' meaning. There is no clear scientific definition (*afaik*).

In the science of psychology it was poisoned by the *"mind-body dualistic"* superstitions, even among the famous researchers.

Already **Charles Darwin** shined some light on evolutionary function of emotions.

**Paul Ekman** coined his famous theory of basic/prototypical emotions and shown their direct linkage with facial expressions among human species. But already it was shown not to be accurate, if not disproved.

**Robert Plutchik** build a nice classification model of emotional responses in a psychoevolutionary context. I am not sure how extensively this particular theory was tested and proven.

**Lisa Feldman-Barret** proposed recently theory of constructed emotions which emphasises their cognitive (and social-adaptive) aspect.

In the field of neuroscience researchers like **Mark Solms** have shown some underlying mechanisms in a deep brain and cortex that are directly involved in generating 'things' that we usually call emotions or feelings.

#### Question

What is the current (2021 CE) **state-of-the-art theory of emotion/affect/feelings**? Who among the top researchers and institutions is trying to solve this problem from a scientific perspective?

Comment: The way this question is titled and written initially is fine but the last paragraph turns it into more of a discussion which is not really the way StackExchange works. If you want to know about the latest findings, then that is fine, but to ask for a discussion on the top researchers and whether their latest findings are scientific or not, StackExchange is not the place. This is a question and answer site. For an overview on the science/pseudoscience of psychology see [my meta answer and others](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2248)

Comment: Sure. I tried my question to be 'what are the current state-of-the-art theories regarded by the scientific community', which I expect to be here, who is working on it. I might elaborate too much on the topic, but only to show that I did some digging on my own, which I don't expect to be extensive.